# Joomla footer not moving down with embeds

Tags: css, joomla

I am working on this site - www.Scottishcrucible.org.uk on joomla but dont have much programming experience so would appreciaite simple answers!

I cant seem to get the footer to move down when I embed things like on this page - http://www.scottishcrucible.org.uk/crucible-forum/forum-posters.html - I also cant work out why it is covering up my title. My work made the template but now refuse to help tweek things so I am trying to work it out with little success!

Im not sure which bit of the css to paste in - the template is RT Gantry
Help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that iframes on your site are set to use the style position:absolute.

This style appears in http://www.scottishcrucible.org.uk/templates/rt_gantry/css/custom.css and http://www.scottishcrucible.org.uk/templates/rt_gantry/css/style1.css

You could always override with an inline style on your iframe (position:static), if you are not confident how updating the main styles will impact your site.

```
<iframe frameborder="1" style="position:static;width:100%; height:400px;" src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.scottishcrucible.org.uk/images/documents/Forumposters/Bennett.pdf&amp;embedded=true">
                            </iframe>
```

Comment: That's great - thanks! Bit scared of breaking the whole site!